# How to make Safari open all tabs in previous session?

Tags: safari, tabs, session

Is it possible to make safari to open all tabs of previous session?

(Currently using the latest Safari 5 on Windows Vista)

Answer (score 2):

found answer myself.

Recently, Safari (5.0.3) on Windows added a new feature. Now you can open all tabs in your last session. It's under the menu “History▸Reopen All Windows From Last Session”. Finally. Safari is the last browser to have this feature.

for other browsers, see
[Link](http://xahlee.info/mswin/browser_restore_session.html)